# gLightBox tries to open a Vimeo video instead of an image

Tags: lightbox

I'm using [gLightBox](https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox) on my website [here](https://arcuridevelopments.com/gallery/) and everytime I click on an image, the pop-up attempts to convert the image into a *Vimeo* iframe embed which is not expected behavior.

When I look at it from my local machine, it works fine and looks like this: [image]

However, when I look at it from my [live site](https://arcuridevelopments.com/gallery/), it looks like this: [image]

If you go to inspect the markup, you'll see that the lightbox is attempting to load a *Vimeo* video, but it should really just load the image.

I am hosting this server on *[GoDaddy](https://ca.godaddy.com)*.

Would anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In your webpage, the img src has '?' sign after the 'jpg' extension which caused glightbox failed to recognize the filename type as image.

So, in the glightbox.js remove the '$' sign in the match function:

```js
if (url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|jpe|gif|png|apn|webp|svg)$/) !== null) {
  return 'image';
}
```

that is:

```js
if (url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|jpe|gif|png|apn|webp|svg)/) !== null) {
```